# Boot completed Broadcast receiver is not working for dynamic registration

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I created a broadcast receiver and registered in in manifest using following approach it is working fine

**static way registering broadcast receiver (working fine)**

```
<receiver
        android:name="DeviceRestartListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </category> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

But when i tried to register the broadcast receiver programmatic (instead of static way) using following way it doesnt work
**Programmetic registering (not working)**

```
DeviceRestartListener dataBroadcastReceiver = new DeviceRestartListener();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(
                    "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")
//registerReceiver(dataBroadcastReceiver, filter); //DOESNT WORK
registerReceiver(dataBroadcastReceiver, filter, "android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED", null); //DOESNT WORK
```

No compilation and run time error. But the receiver is not receiving broadcast after device restarts

Thanks

Comment: "But the receiver is not receiving broadcast after device restarts" -- why would it? After all, your `BroadcastReceiver` instance no longer exists once the process is terminated, let alone on a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Register receiver in code**

When we register a receiver in code, we must unregister it when the app gets destroy (actually, when the Activity or Service that register it, gets destroy).

**Register receiver in manifest**

When we declare it in the manifest, you make it available even if you app is not running.

**When to use which method to register**

Which method to use for registering your BroadcastReceiver depends on what your app does with the system event. I think there are basically two reasons why your app wants to know about system-wide events:

1. Your app offers some kind of service around these events
2. Your app wants to react graciously to state changes

Examples for the first category are apps that need to work as soon as the device is booted or that must start some kind of work whenever an app is installed. Battery Widget Pro or App2SD are good examples for these kinds of apps. For this type you must register the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest file.

Examples for the second category are events that signal a change to circumstances your app might rely on. Say your app depends on an established Bluetooth connection. You have to react to a state change – but only when your app is active. In this case there is no need for a statically registered broadcast receiver. A dynamically registered one would be more reasonable.

There are also a few events that you are not even allowed to statically register for. An example for this is the Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK event which is broadcast every minute. Which is a wise decision because a static receiver would unnecessarily drain the battery.

Answer (score 1):

All the Broadcast receivers will not work even when they are statically declared in manifest or registered dynamically using Application context. for example Intent actions like

```
      Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
```

and

```
      Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON
```

have to be registered dynamically. These actions will not be fired when they are declared in manifest. some Intent actions like

```
    Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED;
    Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK;
    Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED;
```

will be fired when are registered dynamically through context whose window token is not null.(like Activity or Dialog).

similar to this, some of the Intent actions like

```
      Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

will work only when they are registered statically using manifest